# Undo changes in working local folder from specific commit that already pushed

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I have a git repo at BitBucket and after 2 hour, I realize that.. I do mistake and need to undo my local working folder with 2 previous commit.

How I can do that? This is my **git log**

```
commit fd04cfd1c3ed6a80649f018cffc80acfee8d022c
Author: R <r@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Sep 19 14:43:44 2015 +0800

    theme changed.

commit 11783669c8b8c0dc909dbf15aac085a0c497422c
Author: R <r@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Sep 19 14:15:27 2015 +0800

    Modified.. need to change theme..

commit f1c9df7d7f7aec54942e06b70b4908dbfe7b9f17
Author: R <r@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Sep 19 08:29:15 2015 +0800

    Create 2 testing file for:
    - check session level
    - check WHOIS session

commit 41828c1d6f984821d5c7b3cb2d0cac269da2b03e
Author: R <r@hotmail.com>
Date:   Sat Sep 19 01:05:41 2015 +0800

    Prevent others user level and anonymous user from entering PTM level
```

The commit hash **11783669c8b8c0dc909dbf15aac085a0c497422c** are my target to undo all the changes in my local.

Comment: Are you the only one using that repo or not. Do you want to keep the history or do you want to pretend these 2 commits never existed?

Comment: hi @JBNizet , can I keep the history? Maybe I need it this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you like to remove including 11783669c8b8c0dc909dbf15aac085a0c497422c
If you want to remove it locally don't want to push reverted checkin then do:

git reset HEAD f1c9df7d7f7aec54942e06b70b4908dbfe7b9f17

git checkout .

and remove newly added files

If you want to push reverted checkin then do:

git revert fd04cfd1c3ed6a80649f018cffc80acfee8d022c

git revert 11783669c8b8c0dc909dbf15aac085a0c497422c

this will two new commits with revert changes

Answer (score 0):

Use `git revert`. `git revert --help` will explain you what it does and how to use it:

```
git revert f1c9df7d7f..fd04cfd1c3e
```

for example.

Comment: My working folder does not change at all, why sir? I look same with the latest commit

Comment: What exactly happened when executing that command? What is the new output of `git log` after you executed it?

Comment: @RobbNesp after ``git revert``, you should use ``git checkout -- .`` command.